# GridLayout isn't working properly in .kv file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy-language

I'm very new at Kivy. I'm following an example at kivy docs where I came across this following code. bBut it's not working properly.

first.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0
<LoginScreen>:
    f_username: username
    f_password: password
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        cols: 2
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        Label:
            text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            id: username
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Password"
        TextInput:
            id: password
            password: True
            multiline: False
```

This code works fine if i remove the LoginScreen class from both kivy and python file. Like

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return
```

and

```
#:kivy 2.0
    f_username: username
    f_password: password
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        
...
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    pass
```

This means that when you create an instance with the LoginScreen class, the instance becomes GridLayout.

```
# GridLayout
<LoginScreen>:
    f_username: username
    f_password: password

    # Another GridLayout!
    GridLayout:
        ...
```

The LoginScreen is already based on GridLayout, but you are trying to add another gridlayout to the class. In this case, rows and cols are not defined on the outmost gridlayout.

```
#:kivy 2.0

<LoginScreen>:
    f_username: username
    f_password: password

    rows: 2
    cols: 2
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    Label:
        text: "Username"
    TextInput:
        id: username
        multiline: False
    Label:
        text: "Password"
    TextInput:
        id: password
        password: True
        multiline: False
```

Removing the duplicate layout will fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working fine. Can you clear my one doubt? What is f_username and why do use f_ ?

Comment: You can consider them as variables. Since "rows", "cols", "padding", and "spacing" are the attributes of Gridlayout, when you set values on the attributes, the previous values on them are changed.
But Gridlayout doesn't have attributes "f_username" and "f_password". If you set these values, you are creating new attributes. You can set any attribute, like "my_name: Adib".
So, the current "f_username" is the TextInput widget with "id: username", and "f_password" is the TextInput widget with "id: password".

Comment: Thanks Anthony 